# Python remove sublist in a list if specific element inside this sublist

Tags: python, list

For example

```
list_of_specific_element = [2,13]
list = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [13, 12], [13, 14], [15, 13]]
```

I want the sublist including any value inside the list of specific element be removed from the list.
So the element `[2,1],[2,3],[13,12],[13,14]` should be removed from the list.
the final output list should be`[[1,0],[15,13]]`

Comment: Why would `[15, 13]` remain? It does contain a `13`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
listy=[elem for elem in listy if (elem[0] not in list_of_specific_element) and (elem[1] not in list_of_specific_element)]
```

Using list comprehension one-liner

Comment: but don't use list as a var name as it is the name of a built in function

Comment: It is the variable name that the question-asker used

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 That doesn't mean you've to repeat the same *mistake*

Comment: Changed it to listy

Answer (score 2):

You could use set intersections:

```
>>> exclude = {2, 13}
>>> lst = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [13, 12], [13, 14], [15, 13]]
>>> [sublist for sublist in lst if not exclude.intersection(sublist)]
[[1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
list_of_specific_element = [2,13]
set_of_specific_element = set(list_of_specific_element)
mylist = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [13, 12], [13, 14], [15, 13]]
output = [
    item
    for item in mylist
    if not set_of_specific_element.intersection(set(item))
]
```

which gives:

```
>>> output
[[1, 0]]
```

This uses sets, set intersection and list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

A simple list-only solution:

```
list = [x for x in list if all(e not in list_of_specific_element for e in x)]
```

And you really shouldn't call it `list`!

Answer (score 1):

### Filter & lambda version

```
list_of_specific_element = [2,13]
list = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [13, 12], [13, 14], [15, 13]]

filtered = filter(lambda item: item[0] not in list_of_specific_element, list)

print(filtered)

>>> [[1, 0], [15, 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` and `any()` to do the trick like this example:

```
list_of_specific_element = [2,13]
# PS: Avoid calling your list a 'list' variable
# You can call it somthing else.
my_list = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [13, 12], [13, 14], [15, 13]]
final = [k for k in my_list if not any(j in list_of_specific_element for j in k)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
match = [2,13]
lst = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [2, 3], [13, 12], [13, 14], [15, 13]]

[[lst.remove(subl) for m in match if m in subl]for subl in lst[:]]
```

[demo](https://eval.in/806397)